# MongoDB exporter metrics from multiple mongo instance

Tags: mongodb, prometheus, monitoring, grafana, percona

I have multiple mongo docker containers in a replication setup. I want to scrape metrics from all three instance using mongodb exporter and prometheus. I already specified the server info in URI like this

mongodb://mongo-0:27017,mongo-1:27018,mongo-2:27019/?replicaSet=rs0

The mongoexporter only scrape information from the first instance only(mongo-0). How to get the metrics from all three instance so I can view the details of all from a single dashboard on grafana

Comment: What metrics are you missing from the other instances? As far as I can remember (I may be wrong), the persona exporter queries the replica set using the mongo-driver client. So if you're looking for e.g. CPU metrics from the individual nodes, then you won't find them there. (Again I might be wrong, and would have to verify this. Haven't used the exporter in a long time).

Comment: I want metrics like active connections, query operations & cpu usage from all instances but right now the exporter is scraping metrics from the first instance only.
The exporter is successfully connecting to all instance but not scraping metrics from other nodes. How to scrape metrics from multiple nodes using mongoexporter?